# PHP api call header variable retrieval

Tags: php, header

I'm working with an api that returns a number of useful variables within the header response, for example with...

```
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Apache
X-Pages → 1424
```

... I'd like to use the X-Pages variable to form some further logic. How do I retrieve this variable and use it within my php script?

My api currently call looks like this:

```
$username = "XXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
$remote_url = 'XXXXXXXX';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
'header' => $headers

  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file1 = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
```

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I'm calling it through PHP with a basic authorisation request, I can retrieve the body of the call and use that in my code, I just don't know how to access the header that is also being returned (I can see it's there using an api query app) ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm pretty new to working with apis, I'm currently calling the api through the following:


$username = "XXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXX";
$remote_url = 'XXXXXXXX';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
'header' => $headers

  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file1 = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the response headers in [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) after making the call to `file_get_contents` - it'll be automatically populated in the local scope.